# What is optimal font-size (relative to cognitive loading)?

Tags: fonts, ide

I found an interesting article about cognitive loading:
https://stitcher.io/blog/a-programmers-cognitive-load

So, I wonder if it makes sense? Does it really matter and can improve work?

I'd ask it here because there is a lack of user answers and looks like not much of programmers think of font-size of code in that way. Instead, I see only: "More code that fits the screen, the better". I thought of it the same way before reading this article, so now I think that brings it up here will be useful for at least someone other than me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. Perhaps [UX StackExchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) can help.

Comment: Thanks, Flimzy, I was not sure where to ask this question. Agree with you.